# NoSuchElementException issue with state in viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Context: i create a dasboard card with [vico Charts](https://github.com/patrykandpatrick/vico) (particularly, im using column bars) and what im trying to do is, when you tap a column (using markerVisibilityChangeListener), execute an onClick function that i pass as parameter, which is based on update a value in the card (a text); this value update occurs in a viewmodel with the following function:

```
fun updateAverageByPoint(index: Int) {
    try {
        var newValue: Double
        emotionalStateIndexByDate.getOrNull(index).let {
            if (it == null) return;
            newValue = it.index!!
        }
        var avg = 1.0
        if (newValue != 0.0) {
            avg = newValue.div(this.average.value)
        }
        this.average = SummaryValue(
            value = newValue.roundToInt(),
            colorID = usesCase.emotionalColor(newValue)
        )
        this.tendency = SummaryIcon(avg)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString())
    }
}
```

But when i tap, the app closed with te following error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.., PID: 18740
java.util.NoSuchElementException

which has no sense, because i get the new value, so the error is happening when I change the average attribute:

```
// in viewmodel: 
var average by mutableStateOf(SummaryValue(0, R.color.red))
protected set
// the class itself:
        data class SummaryValue(
    val value: Int,
    val colorID: Int,
    val iconID: Int? = null,
)
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this pls?

I tried to use a new SummaryValue class with mutableStateOf for the attribute. Other option was define new attributes:

```
var averageValue by mutableStateOf(0)
    protected set
var averageColor by mutableStateOf(R.color.red)
    protected set
```

In my viewmodel, in order to just update those with the new values:

```
this.averageValue = newValue.roundToInt()
this.averageColor = usesCase.emotionalColor(newValue)
```

But neither of those options worked

Comment: Where does the error occur? Which line?

Comment: the error occurs in lthis line:
this.average = SummaryValue(
            value = newValue.roundToInt(),
            colorID = usesCase.emotionalColor(newValue)
        )
inside the updateAverageByPoint function, when im redefining the attribute in the viewmodel

Comment: provide the full stack trace of exception in logcat, since it easy to identify issue.

Comment: the complete logcat is in here: https://www.reddit.com/r/JetpackCompose/comments/1bl2isa/comment/kw34pb5/